# How to match every value within braces?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have the following lines for which I want to match only the content within internal braces.

So for these 3 lines:

```
{ abv:{1} pwr:{1} dft:{1} valUy:{4066792} }
{ wwqe:{0x342} }
{ heew:{ValStr} abgd:{-} }
```

the output would be:

```
1,1,1,4066792
0x342
ValStr,-
```

I've tried with the following 2 regex testing [here](https://pythex.org/), but I'm not getting values I look for.

```
\{(.*?)\}
(?<=\{).+?(?=\})
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try using `re.findall` with the following regexp pattern:

```
\{([^{}]+)\}
```

This will capture the contents in between curly braces across the entire input.  Note that it ensures that we do not attempt to match anything other than innermost braces.

```
inp = """{ abv:{1} pwr:{1} dft:{1} valUy:{4066792} }
{ wwqe:{0x342} }
{ heew:{ValStr} abgd:{-} }"""

matches = re.findall(r'\{([^{}]+)\}', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['1', '1', '1', '4066792', '0x342', 'ValStr', '-']
```

Comment: Excellent Tim. Thanks so much for your help, it works perfect. One question. Why does your regex work even when within the brackets you are not using escaped braces?

Comment: @GerCas If you're referring to the character class `[{}]`, generally metacharacters do _not_ need to be escaped inside a character class.

Comment: Ohhh, ok. Understood. I tried before posting something like this too `[\{\}]` without success. Good to know. Thanks again

Comment: Actually, you should be able to still escape them with backslash if you want.  The problem with your pattern is that it does the opposite of what you want.  `[\{\}]` matches curly braces, but we want to match across `[^\{\}]`, that is, against _not_ curly braces.